# compile Jasper design file into .jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a `.jrxml` file which is used to generate a jasper report and then a a pdf file from that. for that I used this code.

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/letters/report xml/testreport.jrxml");
```

But I got an issue with `xsd` and `dtd` which is described here. That article introduces a way to solve the issue by using a java program called `LegacyJasperInputStream`.

This is how I should call it.

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(
   new LegacyJasperInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/letters/report xml/testreport.jrxml"))
);
```

My question is what is this `JasperDesign`. Can I compile that into `.jasper`.
If so, how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying....Here we go.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(
                    new LegacyJasperInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/letters/report xml/testreport.jrxml"))
                    );
            JasperReport jasperReport = asperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
            System.out.println("INFO: Report is filled and to be exported to pdf now");

            try {
                // export report to pdf
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/letters/report xml/test.pdf");
                System.out.println("DEBUG: Expported to pdf");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("EXCEPTION: while generating pdf : "+e);
            }
```